# Postprocessing ColorSpace: Windows System with two graphics cards (Quadro and GTX) one AdobeRGB the other sRGB color space

Tags: windows, color-spaces, adobe-rgb

I couldn't find any satisfying answer to this question.

I plan to build a postprocessing PC which has a Quadro K4000 and a GTX680 graphic card installed. I plan to buy two monitors which are:

NEC MultiSync PA272W (AdobeRGB)

LG ELECTRONICS 29UB65-P (sRGB)

I would like to link the NEC monitor to the K4000 and the other to the second graphics card is that possible?

As I read it is possible to build a system with these two graphics cards but I don't know if both of them may be used to display or if the second can only be used for GPU acceleration.
Furthremore, I understood linking both monitors to the same graphics card, will force Windows to switch to sRGB representation and would not consider to utilise AdobeRGB on the NEC.

Is that true?

Would be very interesting if anybody knows, please no guesses to this topic because it is a lot of money which will be invested.

Thanks

Comment: Why use the sRGB monitor at all? It would be best to use the NEC and just reduce the color gamut in the file.

Comment: If this is actually involving a lot of money, I'd suggest paying for professional advice.

Comment: AFAIK what you are trying to do is not possible, GPU drivers don't allow you to work in two color spaces at the same time, even if there are two different GPUs involved - but I might be wrong. As Philip said - get some professional advice, don't ask random people on the internet about things that involve as large sums of money and specialized knowledge as you need.

Comment: I think this is simple and possible. But: you should ask NVIDIA support whether they allow separate ICC profile binding to a dual-card setup. With a single card, with two very different monitor (a pro graphics monitor and a huge Samsung TV) I did this - calibrated, and worked fine. NVIDIA will also be able to answer this question probably.

Comment: BTW: are you sure you need a K4000? You could run a GTX680 SLI setup... CUDA support seems to be decent. On the other hand, K4000 supports multiple monitors. Why do you want this hybrid setup? A K4000 is dominant enough to expect no video cards alongside it, and driver support could be rather disappointing...

Comment: As intended in my question it seems that Windows switches to sRGB color space as soon as it recognizes one monitor which allows only sRGB color space. So the whole wide gamut workflow with K4000 and NEC monitor would be not used! However, I wanted to connect a second monitor which is not that expensive. It seems I have to buy another monitor with 1.07 biollion color range.

@TFuto I think you did not understand that the K4000 is necessary to display AdobeRGB color space.

Comment: That's some pretty heavy duty graphics processing you have. Do you already have the cards? If not, I'd guess that the price to performance ratio is pretty high for PS. ISTR that PS runs well on a "medium-high" card with 2GB VRAM.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 (and other versions, probably) let you choose separate colour profile for each display. This can't be limited based on how displays are connected.

Whether the software which you work in will manage colour properly (i.e. will moving the windows containing the image to the other display preserve colour or will the image be displayed equally in display clone mode) depends on the software itself.

There is no reason to worry about second card not being able to display image separately. Windows had multiple GPU and display support at least since XP.

However, you might want to contact Nvidia support to know whether you will be able to use 10 bit output with GTX680 present in the system.